# Как в .NET по атрибутам объекта определить состояние "красного креста" (ошибку GDI)?

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+

Если в `System::Windows::Forms::Panel`, в `BackgroundImage` подключить файл `.ico`, то, так как данный формат не поддерживается, появится красный крест. Чтобы восстанавливать объект только в случае ошибки, нужно определить это. Следующие свойства не позволяют сделать это:

1. `IsDisposed`
2. `IsAccesability`

Как определить наличие данной ошибки?

Comment: Вообще-то GDI+ поддерживает .ico. Кроме того, Panel красный крест при ошибке не показывает, возможно имелся в виду PictureBox?

Comment: Для начала покажите код, как вы подключаете файл.

Answer (score 0):

Когда компонент не может отрисовать изображение в событии `OnPaint`, выбрасывается исключение, после чего на этом компоненте отрисовывается красный крест.
Предлагаю попробовать следующий код:

```
class RobustPanel : Panel
{
    public bool RedXDetected { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            //RedXDetected = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            RedXDetected = true;
            //throw;
        }
    }
}
```

После добавления изображения на панель проверяем свойство `RedXDetected`.

Нужно ли сбрасывать свойство в `false` при успешной отрисовке - решать вам. Удалите комментарий или делайте это вручную в своём коде.
Вероятно, есть смысл повторно выбросить исключение: `throw`. Тоже решать вам.